# How to read cpu frequency on android device

Tags: android, api, cpu

Is there any Java API for that? How can I read this information.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To have frequency on Android, just read these special files in /sys directory:

```
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq"
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq"
```

You will have current, min and max Frequency allowed.

Comment: Awesome answer Ellis, you really helped me a lot.  One thing that I found in investigating this was that scaling_cur_freq is not necessarily the current CPU frequency, but rather what the kernel thinks the frequency is.  To get the real frequency, you need root access to read cpuinfo_cur_freq.  Also, gaining root access allows you to set the cpu speed, which is quite useful for profiling under best/worst case conditions.

Comment: Hummm It seems to me that even with root access you can't edit the cpuinfo_* files..

Comment: How can we get CPU load or utilization?

Comment: How can these files be read from within an app?

Comment: I notice  subdirectory `policyX` under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/`, what is that?

Answer (score 8):

not MHz, but at least something. [bogoMIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips) value can be useful for you.

```
private String ReadCPUinfo()
 {
  ProcessBuilder cmd;
  String result="";

  try{
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
   byte[] re = new byte[1024];
   while(in.read(re) != -1){
    System.out.println(new String(re));
    result = result + new String(re);
   }
   in.close();
  } catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to convert it to MHz or read it somewhere?

Comment: Any reason you're not just opening /proc/cpuinfo as a file and reading it directly?

Comment: michael, read a wiki page about bogoMIPS, there's a formula. fadden, I'm not sure that file could be simply read from java, just found this code laying around.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in how long your system spent in what state, check out the file

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state
```

I'm not sure, whether root access is necessary for that.

Comment: Root access seems not to be neccesary, unlike for `cpuinfo_cur_freq`.