# Android check CPU frequency?

Tags: android, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect android cpu speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875415/how-to-detect-android-cpu-speed)

How can I check CPU frequency on Android?

Answer (score 0):

You might find in `ActivityManager`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html