# Check if device is dual core

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to check if an Android device is dual core? (Other than `Runtime.availableProcessors()` as it only reports the correct number occasionally.)

I need it as SoundPool doesn't work on dual cores (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17623)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Runtime.availableProcessors()` is the way to do it. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) says:

> Returns the number of processors **available** to the virtual machine [...] at least 1.

I think that the result of this function returns the number of *logical* cores (not physical).

But this does not solve your problem: The Bug-report states that the bug occurs only on Samsung Galaxy S2 and I think that it will be fixed sometime in future.

Comment: The problem is, if I loop this function and print it's results, it says both 1 and 2 on different calls.

Comment: Could you write your own function in C and compile with the NDK?

Comment: This probably doesn't work because many devices shut off the second core unless under heavy load

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this:

```
float ALOUD_MISTAKE = 20; // percent
int WORK_TIME = 1000; // milliseconds

public int work(){
   int workCounter = 0;
   long startTime = System. currentTime();
   long currentTime = System. currentTime();
   while(startTime < currentTime + WORK_TIME){
       currentTime = System. currentTime();
       workCounter++;
   }

   return workCounter;

}

start mainThread1;
check the work time and save it(keep it going)
now start new thread

new Thread(new Runnable(){
   void run(){
      while(true){
          work();
      }
   }
}).start();
```

let them run a bit and now check:

```
if(Math.abs(workTimeThread1 - savedWorkTimeThread1) / workTimeThread1 * 100 > ALOUD_MISTAKE)
{
    you got (number of new threads been started - 1) cores
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4875506/737925

```
private String ReadCPUinfo()
 {
  ProcessBuilder cmd;
  String result="";

  try{
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
   byte[] re = new byte[1024];
   while(in.read(re) != -1){
    System.out.println(new String(re));
    result = result + new String(re);
   }
   in.close();
  } catch(IOException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
 }
}`
```