# Find the processor speed of an Android device in MHz

Tags: android, processor

How can I get processor speed of an Android device in MHz? I'm able to get the speed in terms of [BogoMips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips) by reading `\proc\cpuinfo` file. How can I convert BogoMips to MHz or is there any other way to get the speed in MHz?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875415/how-to-detect-android-cpu-speed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the maximum processor speed (in Hz) into the file:

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq

For instance, the content of that file in my Samsung Galaxy Ace is :

832000

Comment: Nexus One - file not found

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia page on BogoMips (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips) gives a table providing a rough way of estimating between processor clock and bogoMips given the type of processor.