# Mobile Processor Speed

Tags: android, mobile, processor, cpu-speed

How to know the speed of a Mobile Processor in instruction/second? The motive behind this is to find the computational time for a set of instruction and to check the performance.

Comment: Why not just do the measurement yourself? It will only take a second ;) It will be hard to determine how many instructions per second the mobile will handle depending on current system load, the measured instruction intensity and of course available system resources. For this I bet your only option is to actually benchmark the system manually.

Comment: Thankx Daniel, I just found one [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875415/how-to-detect-android-cpu-speed?rq=1) . But, this is the straight forward answer.

Comment: A wide discussion on this topic is also discussed in this link. http://superuser.com/questions/808776/whats-the-difference-between-mobile-and-desktop-processors. But, I could not find any strong point to conclude from the discussion. The question is still open.