# Find out mobile features on Android

Tags: java, android, cpu

Is there a way to find out *by code* some of the features or characteristics of a Android mobile phone?

I'm more interested in information regarding the CPU, stuff like it's processing power, the chipset name, etc.

Am I dealing with this: 1GHz Scorpion processor, Adreno 205 GPU, MSM8255 Snapdragon chipset OR with this: 528 MHz processor, Qualcomm MSM7225 chipset?

Comment: check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Comment: Or this [How to read cpu frequency on android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021054/how-to-read-cpu-frequency-on-android-device)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you want this? Wouldn't it be better to do a small benchmark and see if the CPU is "fast enough"? Otherwise you'd have to *know* about all relevant CPUs out there.

Comment: I wanted to make a improvisation calculus on how many threads (MAX) to allow on a app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) can be used to query certain information about the current Android build, including but not limited to product name, board type, hardware model and CPU instruction set.