# How to disable freqeuncy scaling on android?

Tags: android, cpu, scaling, frequency

How to detect the frequency when running a program on android?
I want detect the CPU usage using the top -m command, but since android kernel by default does frequency scaling, I am afraid the result from "top -m " command is not correct. So I want to disable the frequency scaling for android.
Any solution to this problem?

Welcome any comments!

Comment: To have frequency on Android, just read these special files in /sys directory:
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq"
#cat "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq"


You will have current, min and max Frequency allowed.

Comment: This is a useful solution for me. Hope it can help someone who encounters similar problem.

Comment: The solution is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021054/how-to-read-cpu-frequency-on-android-device