# How to determine graphical performance of a device?

Tags: android

For Android devices, there are older devices who render choppy animations. I'd like to turn animation off for those devices. Is there a way to detect it other than somehow correlating version number with actual device performance?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get a hint on how fast is your device by reading it's CPU frequency (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021054/how-to-read-cpu-frequency-on-android-device) question)

Comment: This answers the question directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION #1:**

You could just let the user decide or include different animation qualities (similar to a <kbd>HD</kbd> | <kbd>SD</kbd> selector.

**OPTION #2:**

Stop blaming the hardware ;o) You could just try to improve your code.

**OPTION #3:**

Run a little test in your app before showing the animations (on app start, maybe). Check how much does it take to perform an action you use as benchmark and decide if you want to run it on that device.