# Cyanogenmod change permission to system files

Tags: android, permissions, cyanogenmod

I have built an application for ROOT android devices. It's open source and the source code is [here](https://github.com/elefher/CpuHandler).
My problem is that, when the code tries to read the file "/sys/block/mmcblk0/queue/scheduler" i get this error

```
06-20 16:17:10.190: W/System.err(7458): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/block/mmcblk0/queue/scheduler: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

That happens only in cyanogenmod OS, i have tried with carbon OS also and works fine!
Please note that i cannot read the file even so when i change the permissions via adb.

When i do a connection to my device via adb shell as root and hit the below command

> cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/queue/scheduler

i get this output

```
noop deadline [row] cfq
```

Manifest

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--These permissions needed for ads-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
...
```

Function which read the content file

```
public static String getStringOfFile(String file) {
    String cpuFreq = "";
    RandomAccessFile reader;
    try {
        reader = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        cpuFreq = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cpuFreq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error simply because `the file does not exist`. Looks like you are trying to access some scheduler files, but the location of these files often depend upon the kernel implementation. You can stay sure that you won't find that particular file at the same place on all kernels, and also will not be present on every device.

Comment: The file exists in the path. i have checked that with adb shell. Also i get this output when i connected as root via adb shell in my device: noop deadline [row] cfq

Comment: Ok, so it's a permission problem. You can't access that file using Java code. Use `cat` command to read the file with superuser permission.

Comment: I really cannot understand what exactly happend here. I have tried a lot of code but nothing. i also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021054/how-to-read-cpu-frequency-on-android-device. Check zed_0xff post. Please keep in mind that i cannot read only that file "/sys/block/mmcblk0/queue/scheduler". For instance, i can read the file "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state" well!