# Android How to judge the performance of CPU ？

Tags: android, performance, cpu

Our game needs to konw the performance of an android phone,and I collect some useful performance parameters. e.g. memerory，cpu core numbers，cpu max frequency.

Howerver, these parameters can not represent the CPU performance fully.  I found some questions talk about this just in general terms and didn't go into details.

Here are 2 links related to the topic  [How to detect android cpu speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875415/how-to-detect-android-cpu-speed?answertab=votes#tab-top)   （To be honest ,I do not Know how SystemClock.uptimeMillis() can test the cpu ）& [How to check if device is *fast* enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426826/how-to-check-if-device-is-fast-enough/34426907#34426907)

Is there any parameter can represent how fast is the device  exactly?

Any link to documentations on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The only reliable judge is the end user. Provide settings for disabling aesthetics and unnecessary features. You can autotune these settings the first time you run by monitoring the FPS while the app incrementally switches them on. However the user must still be able to customise them.

Comment: @Margaret，thank you for your advice! I am agree with the first half,and I have done it. However, I am not sure what you said in the second half,for FPS is an unstable value. When I switch game scene,.e.g. one go into the battle，FPS become lower and you could not say the phone has lower performance. Thus,in our game FPS can be a reference but not a performance parameter. I want a general parameter like IPS of CPU in PC. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple way. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS

Besides what I described in the topic， we can get CPU architecture as a supplement.

```
String abi = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    abi = Build.CPU_ABI;
} else {
    abi = Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0];
}
```

arm64-v8a means high quality cpu so far,thus according to the value of abi,we can get another cpu performance parameter.